# jQuery multi-step form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I Want to Validate Multi-Step Bootstrap From With Jquery validation.

I Set required for 1st input field but the form is submitted without checking jquery validation ...

The Form will be not go save page is the first input field is fill up...

```
<div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
            <p>Step 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
            <p>Step 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
            <p>Step 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form role="form" id="myform" action='/save'>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 1</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input  maxlength="100" type="text"  id="field" name="field" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 2</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 3</h3>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: false,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
            allWells = $('.setup-content'),
            allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $item = $(this);

        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-primary');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
        }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function(){
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
            curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
            isValid = true;

        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                isValid = false;
                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
        }

        if (isValid)
            nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Create a working demo, like a jsFiddle, so we can see the problem and more easily help you.